# Warning: Illegal string offset in meta.php after migrating site

Tags: php, wordpress

I recently migrated a site. Old server cPanel was running PHP 5.3.28 - new one is running 5.4.34; now these errors show up:

```
Warning: Illegal string offset 'sidebar_change' in /home/psdive/public_html/homedir/rdoc/wp-content/themes/RDOC2/RDOC2/includes/tt_meta.php on line 3

Warning: Illegal string offset 'sl_pos' in ...tt_meta.php on line 4

Warning: Illegal string offset 'primary_width' in ...tt_meta.php on line 5

Warning: Illegal string offset 'secondary_width' in ...tt_meta.php on line 6

Warning: Illegal string offset 'special_width' in ...tt_meta.php on line 7
```

---

Here is code:

```
<?php
$meta_test2 = $custom_sidebar->the_meta();
$sb_change = $meta_test2['sidebar_change'];
$sb_style = $meta_test2['sl_pos'];
$primary_width = $meta_test2['primary_width'];
$secondary_width = $meta_test2['secondary_width'];
$special_width = $meta_test2['special_width'];
global $primary_width, $secondary_width, $special_width;
$meta_test3 = $custom_back->the_meta();
$back_change = $meta_test3['back_change'];
$background_color = $meta_test3['background_color'];
$background_url = $meta_test3['background_url'];
$background_repeat = $meta_test3['background_repeat'];
$header_change = $meta_test3['header_change'];
$header2_change = $meta_test3['header2_change'];
$header_url = $meta_test3['header_url']; 
$header_url2 = $meta_test3['header_url2'];
global $back_change, $background_color, $background_url, $background_repeat;
if ($back_change) {?><style type='text/css'>body {background: #<?php echo     $background_color ;?> url("<?php echo $background_url; ?>") <?php echo $background_repeat ;?>;}</style><?php } 
if ($header2_change) { ?><style type='text/css'>.fn-header:before{background-image: url('<?php echo $header_url2; ?>'); } </style><?php } 
if ($header_change) { ?><style type='text/css'>.fn-header:after{ background-image: url('<?php echo $header_url; ?>'); } </style> <?php } 
if ($sb_change == 'Yes' ) { ?><style type='text/css'>.fn-content-layout .fn-sidebar2:before, .fn-content-layout .fn-sidebar1:before {width: 0px;}</style><?php } 
?>
```

Is there a way to fix this code instead of reverting back to PHP 5.3?

Comment: I think you had error reporting turned off on your old server!

Comment: from what I've read, PHP 5.3 ignored many errors, so these Warnings did not pop up

Comment: I think this means `$custom_sidebar->the_meta();` is returning a string, not an array. so you could start with that. However I suspect you could comment out lines 4,5,6 and 7 if everything is working despite the warnings

Comment: `$sb_change = !empty($meta_test2['sidebar_change']) ? $meta_test2['sidebar_change'] : null;`...Repeat for all;

Comment: Check what `print_r($meta_test2);` and `print_r($meta_test3);` return

Comment: Nabil, that fixed everything! Thank you very much. (Now I just have to figure out what it means - I am pretty new to coding and have only done a little tweaking here and there.) Thanks again.